# How to implement Oauth2 two-legged token based security on Mule CE?

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule

I am working on Mule CE and need to implement token based security (preferably) using Oauth2. I have configured the authorization-server and I do see the default mappings in the log file, however when I send message on "/oauth/token" nothing happens.

Similar config of OAuth2 works fine with Spring/Tomcat when deployed as standalone Spring web service application on Tomcat.

Here is my Mule config:

```
<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
    xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/vm/2.0"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.1"
    xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/3.3/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/current/mule-jersey.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.3/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/3.3/mule-pattern.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd ">




    <mule-ss:security-manager>
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
            name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>
    <spring:beans>
        <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <ss:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />
        </ss:authentication-manager>
        <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetailsService">
            <oauth:client client-id="admin"
                authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,client_credentials"
                authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT" scope="read,write,trust"
                access-token-validity="60" />
        </oauth:client-details-service>
        <oauth:authorization-server
            client-details-service-ref="clientDetailsService" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
            <oauth:authorization-code />
            <oauth:implicit />
            <oauth:refresh-token />
            <oauth:client-credentials />
            <oauth:password />
        </oauth:authorization-server>
    </spring:beans>

    <spring:beans>

        <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <spring:bean id="myAuthenticationProvider"
            class="com.sachin.tech.security.MyUserAuthenticationProvider" />

        <spring:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <spring:property name="realmName" value="myCustomerAppRealm" />
        </spring:bean>

        <spring:bean id="oauth2AccessDeniedHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl" />

        <spring:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
            <spring:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        </spring:bean>

        <spring:bean id="tokenStore"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

        <spring:bean id="tokenServices"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
            <spring:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
            <spring:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
            <spring:property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds"
                value="60" />
        </spring:bean>

    </spring:beans>

    <flow name="wsauthentication_2" doc:name="wsauthentication_2">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8098" doc:name="MyHTTPInbound2_2"
            doc:description="wsauthentication_2 Desc">
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo" />
    </flow>

</mule>
```

The mapping seems to be fine in logs:

```
13:48:01,789 DEBUG FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping:125 - Looking for request mappings in application context: org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext@7fe3a7ec: startup date [Tue Apr 23 13:47:56 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
13:48:01,836  INFO FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping:197 - Mapped "{[/oauth/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.handleError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
13:48:01,836  INFO FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping:197 - Mapped "{[/oauth/confirm_access],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.getAccessConfirmation(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>) throws java.lang.Exception
13:48:01,851  INFO FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping:197 - Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
13:48:01,851  INFO FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping:197 - Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[POST],params=[user_oauth_approval],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
13:48:01,851  INFO FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping:197 - Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
```

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Similar config works fine with Mule (on Tomcat/Spring)"? If this works on Mule, what's the issue then?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I mean is that similar config works fine with Tomcat/Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Sprint OAuth can actually work **outside** of a Java web container.

For Mule EE, you can use the [OAuth2 provider from the Enterprise Security package](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Creating+an+OAuth+2.0a+Web+Service+Provider).

For Mule CE, you could try to run an embedded Jetty container and use Mule's Servlet endpoints behind it. That should provide an environment in which Spring OAuth could work. See the Bookstore example, provided with the Mule distribution, for inspiration.

Comment: If Mule EE can use Oauth2, we should also be able to do it using CE by writing some code. 
        
I am not looking for Spring specific implementation. Any Oauth2 server implementation library is fine. 
        
Oauth2 Server Libraries for Java:
        Apache Amber (draft 22)
        Spring Security for OAuth
        Apis Authorization Server (v2-31)
        Restlet Framework (draft 30)
        Apache CXF

Comment: You sure can use one of these libraries to handle OAuth2 requests coming to a custom HTTP inbound endpoint. What the Enterprise Security does is auto-configuring an OAuth2 provider so you don't need to manually create a flow, an inbound endpoint, wire an OAuth2 handler, etc...

Comment: I am working with CE hence dont have Enterprise Security feature. I am working with Apache CXF now. Please let me know if you have any exposure to implementing two legged security using CXF on Mule.